# Docker wordpress and mysql : Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php

Tags: wordpress, docker

I am trying to setup a local website on my Mac with Docker and the following docker-composer.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - wordpress_db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:php7.4-apache
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}

volumes:
  wordpress_db:
```

WORDPRESS DB constants are defined in a .env file.

Running `docker-composer up -d` is OK, and **I can enter my database using a GUI** like Sequel Ace. But when I go to the website on http://localhost:8000 I get this error :

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 1987
> No such file or directory

I tried switching localhost to 127.0.0.1 for the DB_HOST constant in the wp-config.php file but it does not work either. Instead of the "No such file or directory" message I get :

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 1987
> Connection refused

What hostname should I use for Wordpress to connect to the database?

Comment: My docker file is almost identical to yours, and I use "db:3306" for the host.  Not sure if this will fix your problem but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Oh your answer gave me the answer and I learned something from it : I had to set the DB_HOST constant to "db" in the wp-config.php file. Thank you!